# One array to four arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, multidimensional-array, amcharts

I have one array like this:

```
[{
    "coin": "AION",
    "profit": "3.10",
    "timestamp": "2021-01-26 00:48:01"
},
{
    "coin": "BTC",
    "profit": "77.00",
    "timestamp": "2021-01-26 00:08:04"
},
{
    "coin": "AION",
    "profit": "4.00",
    "timestamp": "2021-01-26 01:08:01"
},
{
    "coin": "BTC",
    "profit": "78.10",
    "timestamp": "2021-01-26 01:08:04"
}]
```

But what i actually need is four (four is variable) arrays:

```
array coins:
[{ "AION", "BTC" }]
(variable with extra coins, depending on the first array i already have) > AION, BTC, ETH, ZIL, ARK, etc....

array profit[AION]:
[{ "3.10", "4.00" }]

array profit[BTC]:
[{ "77.00", "78.10" }]
(Variable extra coins/profits) [ETH, ZIL, ARK, etc...]

array timestamp:
[{ "2021-01-26 00:48","2021-01-26 01:08" }]
(Variable extra timestamps depending on first array i already have)
```

I need this to fill chartsData array for am4charts.LineSeries.

Can someone help me please? Or is there any better option for this?

Answer (score 0):

This is the kind of problem where you're iterating over elements of an array and grouping some stuff depending on some rules.

It's a good use case for [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) (although you can do the same thing with other methods)

I would do something like this function:

```
function indexByCoins(coinsArray) {
    const coinsProfitByCoin = coinsArray.reduce((accumulator, coinInfo) => {
        const { coin, profit, timestamp } = coinInfo

        if (!accumulator[coin]) {
            accumulator[coin] = []
        }

        accumulator[coin].push({ profit, timestamp })
        return accumulator
    }, {})

    return coinsProfitByCoin
}
```

It doesn't do *exactly* as you asked, instead it groups the profit of each entry with its timestamp. So you'd get:

```
{
  AION: [
    { profit: '3.10', timestamp: '2021-01-26 00:48:01' },
    { profit: '4.00', timestamp: '2021-01-26 01:08:01' }
  ],
  BTC: [
    { profit: '77.00', timestamp: '2021-01-26 00:08:04' },
    { profit: '78.10', timestamp: '2021-01-26 01:08:04' }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let arr=[{
    "coin": "AION",
    "profit": "3.10",
    "timestamp": "2021-01-26 00:48:01"
},
{
    "coin": "BTC",
    "profit": "77.00",
    "timestamp": "2021-01-26 00:08:04"
},
{
    "coin": "AION",
    "profit": "4.00",
    "timestamp": "2021-01-26 01:08:01"
},
{
    "coin": "BTC",
    "profit": "78.10",
    "timestamp": "2021-01-26 01:08:04"
}]
let timestampArr=[...new Set(arr.map(item=> item['timestamp']))]
let coinArray=[...new Set(arr.map(item=> item['coin']))]
let AionProfilt=[],btcProfit=[];
arr.map(item=>{
  if(item.coin==='BTC')
    AionProfilt.push(item.profit)
   else
    btcProfit.push(item.profit)
})
console.log(coinArray,AionProfilt,btcProfit,timestampArr)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function `Array.prototype.reduce` for grouping and building the desired output.

```js
const array = [{    "coin": "AION",    "profit": "3.10",    "timestamp": "2021-01-26 00:48:01"},{    "coin": "BTC",    "profit": "77.00",    "timestamp": "2021-01-26 00:08:04"},{    "coin": "AION",    "profit": "4.00",    "timestamp": "2021-01-26 01:08:01"},{    "coin": "BTC",    "profit": "78.10",    "timestamp": "2021-01-26 01:08:04"}],
      result = array.reduce((a, {coin, profit, timestamp}) => {
        a.coins.push(coin);
        a.timestamps.push(timestamp);
        (a.profits[coin] || (a.profits[coin] = [])).push(profit);

        return a;
      }, {coins: [], profits: {}, timestamps: []});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```